# Using jQuery to highlight unique div when it is in the center of the window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several divs with id="scroll_1", "scroll_2", "scroll_3", etc... When any of these divs is in the center of the window, I want to use jQuery highlight and/or change the background color of whichever div is in the center of the window. Currently the background color changes once it is in the center of the screen but I am having issues changing it back to original background color once it is no longer in the center (i.e the user has scrolled down/up to another scroll_x id.

**Edit** the only relevant css code I have is:

```
[id^=scroll_]{
background-color:white;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {      
    var window_height = $(window).height();
var obj_height = $('#scroll_1').height(); //height of object we are scrolling past
var top = $('#replyer').offset().top + (obj_height /2); //position on screen to start highlighting #scroll_x

    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollMiddle = $(window).scrollTop() + ((window_height/2) - (obj_height /2));

    if (scrollMiddle >= top) {
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop()+ ((window_height/2) - (obj_height /2)),
                currentPosition = 0;
    $('div[id^="scroll_"]').each(function() {//iterate over #scroll_x and only change background until another #scroll_x is in the middle of the screen
            currentPosition = $(this).offset().top;
            if (currentPosition >= scrollPosition) {
            $(this).prev(function(){
                $(this).css('background-color',"#aaa"); //change previous #scroll_x back to original background color - Not Working Currently
            });

                return false; // break the loop
                }

                $(this).css('background-color',"#ccc"); //currently changes background of #scroll_x once in middle of screen but stays highlighted when scrolling up/down to previous/next iteration of #scroll_x
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div id="replyer">
    Top line before repeating divs
</div>
<div id="scroll_1">
    First object to scroll over.
</div>
<div id="scroll_2">
    Want to highlight div currently in the middle of screen
</div>
<div id="scroll_3">
    Only div in middle of screen should be highlighted (background change)
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the css so that we can quickly try this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're after, but here is a demo that will change the object that overlaps the middle of the browser to green.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2ULW/1/

Full source:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Scroll test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background: #000;
  }
  [id^=scroll_]{
    background-color:#aaa;
    height: 600px;
  }
  #replyer {
    height: 400px;
    background: white;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="replyer">
    Top line before repeating divs
  </div>
  <div id="scroll_1">
      First object to scroll over.
  </div>
  <div id="scroll_2">
      Want to highlight div currently in the middle of screen
  </div>
  <div id="scroll_3">
      Only div in middle of screen should be highlighted (background change)
  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {      
  var window_height = $(window).height();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollMiddle = $(window).scrollTop() + (window_height/2);
    $('div[id^="scroll_"]').each(function() {
      elTop = $(this).offset().top;
      elBtm = elTop + $(this).height();
      if (elTop < scrollMiddle && elBtm > scrollMiddle) {
        $(this).css('background-color',"#00ff00");
      } else {
        $(this).css('background-color',"#aaa");
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **+1** This [**SO Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1685536/1195891) also shows a resize event added on.

Answer (score 1):

By default your container div need to have these css properties:

```
div.container { overflow:auto; height:auto; }
```

To block the container with 470*180px size you add this:

```
div.container-closed { overflow:hidden; width:470px; height:180px; }
```

After, on the click, you remove the class .container-closed for removing overflow:

The jquery code:

```
// by default we block the size with JS
$("#div").addClass("container-closed");
// click event
$("#trigger").click( function() {
      $("#div").toggleClass("container-closed");
});
```